# A strange issue... No code changes getting reflected

Tags: netbeans, applet

I am using netbeans to develop an applet, i have a piece of code which looked like this:

```
ipAddresss = DEFAULT_IP;
 System.out.println("portlet.services.hostname:" + ipAddresss);
```

Now I changed it to something like this:

```
 ipAddresss = DEFAULT_IP;
  System.out.println("portlet.services.hostname using default IP Address:" + ipAddresss);
```

But no matter what I do, it sill keep on printing: portlet.services.hostname:null

I have tried deleting all .netbeans folder from documents and settings, tried creating new project, but now i am completely baffled by this issue...

So, the problem is, no matter what I do, no change is getting reflected when I run the program. Can there be a java applet cache, netbeans cache, i am not sure why...

Comment: Did you save before compiling? I'm not familiar with netbeans, but some IDE's won't auto-save your files before compiling, meaning they just compile the outdated version unless you save the new one.

Comment: yes, saved, save all, try to change timestamp outside of ide, nothing seems to work...

Comment: You are sure you are looking at the right lines of code?
The System.out.println should print portlet.services.hostname and you see portlet.pmm.services.hostname (Notice pmm)

Comment: ipAddress is a String variable, DEFAULT_IP is a constant defined as public static final string DEFAULT_IP = "127.0.0.1:8000"

Comment: Ok, but he's saying the line you edited was printing "portlet.services.hostname:" + ipAddresss, but the output was "portlet.pmm.services.hostname:null", where'd the "pmm" come from? Not the line you edited.

Comment: @ccheneson, sorry for confucion, I intended to remove word pmm from post, but it was left out...

Comment: BTW, you might want to make the topic name a little more descriptive. It doesn't say anything about the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue, I was including a jar in project compilation, which had exact same class as the file i am trying to run, netbeans always picked class from that jar instead of newly compiled one...